# Smoothness of fibers vs smoothness of total space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $f:X \to Y= \mathbb P^n$ be a flat morphism. We define condition $S_k$ for such morphisms whose total space over every $k$-dimensional linear space is smooth, namely:
$$f\in S_k \text{ if for every linear space $\mathbb P^k \subset \mathbb P^n$, $f^{-1}(\mathbb P^k)$ is smooth.}$$

I want to know if the following is true:

> $S_i \subsetneqq S_j$ if $i<j$.

The inclusion $S_0\subset S_n$ is the well-known fact, so this can be seen as an enhancement of it. The strict inclusion is related to [one of my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3502704/smoothness-of-general-divisors-in-a-pencil-with-base-locus).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get it. Suppose that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a flat morphism, locally of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$ and each fiber $f^{-1}(y)$ is a smooth scheme over $\mathbb{C}$, then $f$ is a smooth morphism. So it seems that you don't assume that $f$ is locally of finite type?

Comment: @Slup It is locally of finite type (I should say more clearly that $X$ is a variety over $\mathbb C$). But I would like some intermediate result: only assume smoothness of total space over some $\mathbb P^k$ instead of smoothness of every fiber.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Could you please provide a reference for the well-known fact that $S_0\subset S_n$?

Comment: @Slup $S_0$ corresponds to the smoothness of every fiber. Then $f$ is smooth as a morphism, as you mentioned. Then the composition with the trivial map $Y \to { \rm Spec} \mathbb C$ is still smooth, and the fiber is just $X$.